# How can we add views dynamically in already inflated view in listview?

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

Is it possible to add views dynamically by doing this :

getView() :

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        HeaderViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        Map.Entry<String, List<FindTopicFragment.MaintainTopicModel>> hashMap = getItem(position);

        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_group_list_header, null);
            viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder();
            viewHolder.header_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_text);
            viewHolder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearItems);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            setItems(hashMap.getValue().get(position).topicModels, position, viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.header_text.setText("" + hashMap.getKey());

        return convertView;
    }
```

adding views in already inflated view in list view :

```
private void setItems(List<FindTopicFragment.MaintainTopicModel> modelList, int position, HeaderViewHolder holder) {
        holder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        System.out.println("===============================");

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_group_list_row, null);
        TextView group_list_header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_list_header);

        for (FindTopicFragment.MaintainTopicModel model : modelList) {
            System.out.println(model.topicKey);
            group_list_header.setText("" + model.topicKey);
            holder.linearLayout.addView(group_list_header);
        }
        System.out.println("===============================");
    }
```

I have resolved it by doing this. Inflated a view inside the for loop which will create a new row each time.

```
    private void setItems(List<FindTopicFragment.MaintainTopicModel> modelList, int position, HeaderViewHolder holder) {
            holder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            System.out.println("===============================");

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            for (FindTopicFragment.MaintainTopicModel model : modelList) {
                System.out.println(model.topicKey);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_group_list_row, null);
            TextView group_list_header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_list_header);
                group_list_header.setText("" + model.topicKey);
                holder.linearLayout.addView(group_list_header);
            }
            System.out.println("===============================");
        }
```

Thanks guys for valuable suggestions.

Comment: Are you facing any issues?

Comment: yes, here it is :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Try using,
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_group_list_header, parent, false); instead of convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_group_list_header, null);

Comment: Actually the problem is the group_list_header is already a parent of inflated view, and you are trying to add in another parent holder.linearlayout. If you will try to add new view then problem will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

**group_list_header** already has a parent , which is **view**. So adding this to another viewgroup, **holder.linearLayout** is giving the error. I believe the correct line should be

**holder.linearLayout.addView(view);**